# React Router not redirecting for every path

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having a nested react router component.
Whenever route matches /home/:id, the home component is invoked which has further routes like /home/store.

Now, whenever i type **/home/ANY**, it successfully redirects to **/home/store**.
But it does not work for **/home/store/ANY** and i get an empty page.
I want that whatever comes next to **/home/store/ANY** should redirect to **/home/store**

Home Component

```
<Switch>
          
<Route path='/home/store' exact>
  <Store />
</Route>
          
<Route
  path='*'
 render={({ location }) => redirectWrapper('/home/store', location)}
/>

</Switch>
```

Redirect Wrapper Function

```
export function redirectWrapper(path, location) {
  return (
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: path, state: { from: location } }}></Redirect>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, why don't you try to add a Route in Home component like:

```
<Switch>
      
  <Route path='/home/store' exact>
     <Store />
  </Route>
      
  <Route
    path='*'
    render={({ location }) => redirectWrapper('/home/store', location)}
  />

  <Route 
    path='/home/store/(.*)'
    render={({ location }) => redirectWrapper('/home/store', location)}
  />

</Switch>
```

Comment: It will not provide a general solution, e.g. /home/store/:any/:any would still give empty page.I want that no matter what is after /home/store, it always redirects to /home/store

Comment: Ciao, I updated my answer with a solution that could be a general solution.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem got solved by making a default route to /home, if none of the path matches.